# Scala play Unit test controller 2.6.x - object Execution in package concurrent is deprecated: Please see 2.6 migration guide

Tags: scala, playframework, controller, mocking, executioncontext

Trying to follow the migration guide from Scala play framework version 2.6 as from:
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Highlights26

and after upgrading my tests are breaking:

```
val controller = new ProductController(stubControllerComponents().asInstanceOf[ProductControllerComponents])
```

I get:

```
> object Execution in package concurrent is deprecated: Please see
> https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#Execution
```

This is my controller declaration:

```
class ProductController @Inject()(cc: ProductControllerComponents)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
    extends ProductBaseController(cc)
```

and my injected execution context is "executionContext: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext"

I'm following the official play framework 2.6 examples, but still test is not compiling throwing the error msg above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [playframework/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Controller.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Controller.scala)

```
  /**
   * The default execution context provided by Play. You should use this for non-blocking code only. You can do so by
   * passing it explicitly, or by defining an implicit in your controller like so:
   *
   * {{{
   *   implicit lazy val executionContext = defaultExecutionContext
   * }}}
   */
  def defaultExecutionContext: ExecutionContext = controllerComponents.executionContext
```